# Android. AsyncTasks

Tags: android, ddms

I'm using an ad network to display some ads in my app. The `loadAd` function from their library sometimes causes the emulator to freeze (maybe because of some firewall issues).

Anyway, I've since moved to using `AsyncTasks` in which I do the actual call of that `loadAd` method (so the UI doesn't freze anymore) which requests the banner or whatever from their servers.

Whenever I restart my `Activity`, the `onDetroy` method of the `Activity` is called. In there, I call the `AscynTask's` `cancel` method so it will cancel the task and ... presumably stop/remove the thread.

Looking through the DDMS I'v noticed the below things:

See snapshot: http://bayimg.com/EAkBaAaEH

Every time I call the `execute` method of the `AsyncTask`, two `AsynkTasks` (#1 and #2) are created which seem to not go away (be killed) when I call the `cancel(true)` method in the `onDestroy().

After the `Activity` restarts, another two `AsyncTasks` threads are created (#3 and #4).

After another restart of the `Activity` one more `AsynkTask` is created (#5).

**How can i actually kill the tasks? As in stop their execution entirely? Or do they actually stop and I'm just misinterpreting the DDMS?**

Comment: When cancel is called asyntask doinBackground will continue its job and when it finishes, instead of onPostExecute .. OnCancelListener  will be  called

Comment: Well, after the Ad load and everything (after the things listed in the `doInBackground` are done), it still appears in the `DDMS`. Why is that? Why doesn't it disappear from DDMS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you are not doing a while(true)(long continous task) kind of thing in Asynctask doinBackground, asynctask shld not be used for long/continous processes in background thread , if its a small background task it will finish and instead of onPostExecute oncancellistener will be called if cancelled was called during doinbackground execution...

as for still remaining in the DDMS check this :
[AsyncTask thread still there after execute, is that normal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6714085/asynctask-thread-still-there-after-execute-is-that-normal)

its nothing alarming just idle threads , As asynctasks run in a thread pool. idle threads wait for next asynctask  to be executed

Comment: One more quick thing ... When the `onCancelled` method of an `AsyncTask` is called, will that force stop the execution of anything there is in the `doInBackground` method? If there is a `while(1)` in there, when I call `cancel(true)` will that "kill" everything, whatever it may be? Is it a guarantee that the thread will stop? Or would I have to do something in the `onCancelled` method to force the code to stop (depending on the code in the `doInBackground`. Maybe set a flag or something.)?

Comment: there is a method isCancelled() in Asyntask check its boolean value in While(true) loop if true break out.. ... http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#isCancelled()

Comment: Yes, I was just looking at that 1 minute ago. :) Excellent. Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: Also note asynctask is thread pool based , so if your threadpool limit is reached which i think is 5 (not exactly sure) new asynctask will go in wait state and will only execute when one previous thread finishes... just a heads up i had one asynctask with while(true) in service and few in activities and all of a sudden new asynctask stopped executing doinbackgrounds. that baffled me alot :) so lettin u know